# A first chance exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I am developing C# windows forms app,I am using chart control. I need to add data points to chart for every 1 sec using cross thread with InvokeRequired and BeginInvoke.I got the following message in the Output window:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.Targetinvocationexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I don't know where it is coming exactly but it is crashing my application completely.Please guide me.

```
 public void AddNewPoint(DateTime timeStamp, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series ptSeries1, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series ptSeries2, double Y1value, double Y2value)
    {
        if (this.chart1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {                  
                this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeStamp.ToOADate(), Y1value);
                this.chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(timeStamp.ToOADate(), Y2value);
                if( ((count % 60) == 0)&&(count!=0))
                {                
                    mviewcount += 60;
                    viewcount += 60;                    

                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
                    //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 20;
                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries1.Points[count - 1].XValue).ToOADate(); 
                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries1.Points[count - 1].XValue).AddMinutes(1).ToOADate();                        
                    min = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
                    max = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;
                }

                if (count >= 60)
                {
                    if ((count >= viewcount) && (count <= mviewcount))
                    {                            
                        chart1.Series[0].Points[0].AxisLabel = System.DateTime.FromOADate(chart1.Series[0].Points[count - 1].XValue).ToString();
                        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = max;
                        //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size;
                    }
                }
                chart1.Update();
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();

            }));
        }
    }

    public void AddData() //calling using thread
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (flag) // making flag true using timer for every 1sec
            {
                flag = false;
                DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

                double Y1 = 0.0;
                double Y2 = 0.0;

                Y1 = getY1(count);
                Y2 = getY2(count + 1);
               
                AddNewPoint(timeStamp, chart1.Series[0], chart1.Series[1], Y1, Y2);
                
                count++;
            }
           Thread.Sleep(1);           
         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what line of code if leading to this exception?

Comment: No. Actually my app hat to run for continuously 1 week. To test that, I kept long run. After 24 hours, I got this exception. So i didn't used debugger to see the exact line of code. I got exception in program.cs ''Application.Run(new Frm_Main());" .Please help me.

Comment: If your program crashed with an unhandled exception, you should at least be able to recover the exception details and stack trace from the Windows Event Log.

Comment: @cordan: sorry, Is this overflow because of heap memory? If it is,how to clear the heap memory?

Comment: Impossible to say what happened without more details, but it's likely a numeric overflow. i.e. you ran out of bits when trying to add two numbers together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110797/discussion-between-sowjanya-attaluri-and-codran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Well, you may need a better design approach. 
1. For the duration of 2-3 weeks, collect the information / data points in your own data structure. Two List would do in your case. 
2. Let the chart render only a selected portion of the data, upon user request. This is called pagination. For instance, the chart would show the first 1000 data points, and clicking a "Next" button would show the next 1000 data points. You can also provide text boxes to supply a range. 
3. This reduces the load on chart 
4. Separate the UI rendering and data collection logic

Also make sure that AddData() is not running on the UI thread.
An indefinite while loop on the main thread can lead to overflow exceptions eventually.

Try this:
1. Add a Timer control to your form
2. Change your AddData method like the following:

```
public void AddData()
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Tick += (s, e) => 
    {
        flag = false;
        DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

        double Y1 = 0.0;
        double Y2 = 0.0;

        Y1 = getY1(count);
        Y2 = getY2(count + 1);

        AddNewPoint(timeStamp, chart1.Series[0], chart1.Series[1], Y1, Y2);
        Thread.Sleep(1);

        count++;
    };

    timer1.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: I am making flag true using UI timer control for every 1sec. Is this one increase the app memory?

Comment: Can you please show the code that calls AddData() ?

Comment: I am using user defined thread for every one millisecond interval to check the flag is true or not.                                                                          Thread t1 = new Thread(AddData);
t1.Start();

Comment: okay, I think i got the root cause now. Basically, the chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY is getting called 1000*60*60*24 times a day, that is a whopping 86400000. I don't think the vanilla chart control can handle so much data points.

You can try clearing the data points every hour, or else, reducing the frequency of calling AddData

Comment: Yes exactly.I need to update graph for every 1 second and it has to run for 2-3 weeks. But app is closing with in one day and I observed memory leak also. Could you plese tell me where I need to modify my source code for better performance.

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri Well, you may need a better design approach. 
1. For the duration of 2-3 weeks, collect the information / data points in your own data structure. Two List<double> would do in your case. 
2. Let the chart render only a selected portion of the data, upon user request. This is called pagination. For instance, the chart would show the first 1000 data points, and clicking a "Next" button would show the next 1000 data points. You can also provide text boxes to supply a range.
3. This reduces the load on chart
4. Separate the UI rendering and data collection logic

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I will try to design the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110821/discussion-between-sunil-the-techie-and-sowjanya-attaluri).

Answer (score 0):

It seems "First chance exceptions" are frequent (enough) in VS, were you running this continuosly while still in Debug mode, for 24 hours? You probably wouldn't get this exception if the program was release compiled and not being debugged

Comment: You mean, We did not got this exception in releae mode. am I right?

Comment: Yes, have you run your program for 24+ hours in Release mode without getting this exception? If so, it's a known issue in VS debugging environment. If you still encounter this exception in Release mode then I was wrong, but it's worth a try!